# Laravel API push notifications to flutter

Tags: mysql, laravel, api, flutter, push-notification

I want to send notifications from Laravel API with MySQL database to flutter app to tell the user that there are new products!, how can I do that **without Firebase**?

Comment: You can use https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications then whenever you API returns new products you can write some app logic that will generate the notification for the user.

Comment: you need something to trigger the application while it is killed. You need to use firebase on android and APNS on iOS. If the app is in the foreground or in the background you can use the flutter_local_notification plugin

Comment: @SamiKanafani I don't want to use firebase at all!

Comment: @F-1 that's local notifications, what about push notifications?

Comment: If you don't want to use firebase, you could use OneSignal - https://pub.dev/packages/onesignal_flutter

Answer (score 1):

After searching, it turned out that [OneSignal](http://%20pub.dev/packages/onesignal_flutter) package is the best for flutter and web notifications. Hope this answer will help anyone struggling with notifications.